# Database persistence based JMS messaging in Jboss EAP 7.0

Tags: jboss7.x, jboss-eap-7

I am trying to configure JDBC database based persistence for JMS messaging in JBoss  Version 7.0.6.GA.

When I look at JBoss 7.0 docs - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuring_messaging/configuring_persistence, I don't see any documentation about "Messaging Journal Persistence Using a JDBC Database".

But when I look at JBoss 7.1 docs - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html/configuring_messaging/configuring_persistence#messaging_journal_persistence_using_a_jdbc_database, it does details about "Messaging Journal Persistence Using a JDBC Database".

Do that mean JBoss 7.0 EAP doesn't support database persistence based JMS messaging? Do I need to migrate to JBoss 7.1 to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at JBoss 7.1 [release notes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/7.1.0_release_notes/?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001Css5AAC#messaging), I can conclude that we can use JDBC to persist JMS messages only after JBoss 7.1.x and above. This feature is not supported in JBoss 7.0 EAP.